# How to get values of variables after simulation in open modelica?

Tags: variables, simulation, modelica, openmodelica

I've simulated a model in open modelica, now is it possible to get values of all variables that they had during the simulation? If yes, how can I get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you simulate you can give outputFormat="csv" and then you get a result file Model_res.csv containing all variable values for all the time steps. You can then open this file in Excel if you want.
https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/OpenModelica.Scripting.simulate.html

In OpenModelica Connection Editor (OMEdit) you go to Simulation->Simulation Setup, tab Output and select csv.

Comment: thanks, I got output result through **OMShell** but in **OMEdit** I dont seem to have **simulation setup** under the **simulation** tab,
![OMEdit Window](http://i.imgur.com/8YzLWaO.jpg)

Comment: Not under the Simulation tab. Select Simulation from the menu, then Simulation Setup, then the Output tab.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  Normally, when you run OpenModelica, you'll get a results file.  This file contains all the simulation data for all variables.

How you read that file depends on what platform you are running on and what tools you are using.  Is that the issue?